# My CSS code might contain something that is should not

Tags: html, css

I am doing a course and there is a programming exercise that is needed for a grade, the others worked fine but this one is weird. I keep getting these problems.

The 'NEW' labels within  tags should have a color of '#fa9f42' (+ 1 related test)
The element with the ID 'copyright' should have a font-size of 0.75em

Here is my code where I have it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E0E0E2;
}

h1 {
  color: #721817;
}

h2 {
  color: #721817;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

h2 span {
  color: #FA9F42;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

#copyright {
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

this is the readme:

1. Open the `styles.css` file.
2. Add a CSS rule for the `body` element that sets the background color to `#E0E0E2`.
3. Add a CSS rule for the `h1` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
4. Add a CSS rule for the `h2` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
5. Add a CSS rule for the `center-text` CSS class that aligns the text to `center`.
6. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `logo`. Set its left and right margins to `auto` and changes its display to a `block` element.
7. Add a CSS rule for all `span` elements that are children of `h2` elements that sets the text color to `#FA9F42` and its font size to `0.75em`.
8. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `copyright`. Set its top padding to `12` pixels and its font size to `0.75em`.

I tried resubmitting but with no help.

Comment: Does it give you any information as to why or what causes it to fail? The only thing I can think of is that you can combine #3 and #4 into a single rule

Comment: You CSS rules just look fine to me.

Comment: Did you try the no. 7 answer with '#fa9f42' all small letters? It will not make any difference to the output but in an online judge it might. If you didn't you should try it.

Comment: `h2 span` should be `h2>span`

Comment: I would try @Alohci's suggestion of **h2 > span**. **h2 span** will change ALL spans no that are under h2 no matter where its in the h2. But h2 > span will only change a span that is a direct child of h2.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `h2 span` to `h2>span` somehow not only fixed the first error, but also the second one. Thanks for the help.